# how to package a python rabbitmq consumer in a docker image

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq listener running in a python file. I could simply run it as

```
python .\src\rabbitmq_daemon.py
```

But when I run it in docker file given below.

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN \
 apt-get update && \
 python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

#CMD ["python", "-m", "src", "rabbitmq_daemon.py"]
CMD python /usr/src/app/src/rabbitmq_daemon.py
```

It isn't running as a background process. When I open my docker interactive session, it just gives the python console as given below.

```
> docker run -it doc-extr:6
Python 3.9.15 (main, Nov 15 2022, 21:37:24)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
```

I have tried the following as well but the result is the same.

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "src", "rabbitmq_daemon.py"]
```

I was expecting an application to be running and the terminal shows my logs.

I even tried a dry run with the rabbitmq server. it doesn't seems to be connecting to the rabbitmq server

How do I connect to the rabbitmq server from within a docker container.

Comment: What's actually in the `rabbitmq_daemon.py` script?  Have you verified the script is where you expect it to be in the image (`docker run --rm doc-extr:6 ls ./src`)?

Comment: (This probably isn't your problem, but a Docker container can't run a background process; you need to set your consumer process to run in the foreground.  The usual symptom of that is the container just exiting, not getting a Python REPL.)

Comment: My rabbitmq_daemon.py just initiates the following
```
channel_input.basic_consume(queue=APP_CONFIG['INPUT_QUEUE'], on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel_input.start_consuming()

```
it basically starts consuming the channel messages

Comment: Any idea how to run this as a background process in docker?

Comment: Have you ever tried to run this or a similar setup in Compose?  If you `docker build --pull` your image (the `--pull` is important) does it work better?  (This is a hypothesis around your local `python:3.9` image not being the official image, and having an incorrect `ENTRYPOINT`.)

Comment: @DeepakBandela please provide a git repository I (or someone) can clone to see this behavior. At this time you're asking us to guess what the issue is when it would be *trivial* to provide a way to reproduce it. I maintain Pika and I'm sure I could easily figure out your issue. See [this repository](https://github.com/lukebakken/pika-1395/tree/main) for an example of how I run Pika programs in Docker.